# Writing RDD to elasticsearch taking time in Spark streaming scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-streaming

I developed spark streaming(reeiver approach) which is reading data from kafka and processing data and writing into elasticsearch.

same code was developed in java(now we are writing same code in spark scala) and when we are comparing with java performance, spark is not doing well.

What I have observed is when we are writing to ES, its taking time.

Here is my highlevel code:

```
val kafkaStreams: util.List[DStream[String]] = new util.ArrayList[DStream[String]]

for(i <- 0 until topic_threads){
      var data = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,kafkaConf,topic).map(line => line._2)
      kafkaStreams.add(data)
    }
```

> //below union improves the performance as per spark 1.6.2
>   documentation

```
val unifiedStream = ssc.union(kafkaStreams)


unifiedStream.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
if(flagY){
   val dataES = unifiedStream.map(rdd => processData(rdd))
   dataES.foreachRDD(rdd => {
     ElasticUtils.saveToEs(rdd, index_Name, index_Type)
})
```

In processData method, I am just parsing the data which we have red from kafka.

Could anyone please let me know your experiene or suggestions to improve the spark steaming(scala) receiver approach performance.

Due to this low performance, batches are piling up and its increasing delay in batch scheduling..

Comment: Where is the slowdown happening?

Comment: when it is writing to ES - ElasticUtils.saveToEs(rdd, index_Name, index_Type)

Comment: You can try to increase the number of partitions before writing to elasticsearch and also the number of executors in your spark application.

Comment: Is there a reason to use the receiver-based implementation? The `direct` Kafka connector is more efficient.